# Test Highcharts wrapped in a React Component with Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, enzyme

When I `mount(<myHighchartsComponent />)` my highcharts doesnt render in the div it was supposed to.
All that I get is:

```
<div id="579a8c5de9cf144f0c7653df" style="width: 100%; height: 94%;"></div>
```

The component is being rendered perfectly in the browser.

More details:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.chart = new highcharts.Chart(this.options);
}


render() {
    return <div id={this.props.widget.id}></div>;
  }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, Diego! Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to work with?

Comment: Have you tried to use Highcharts in the way like here: http://www.highcharts.com/blog/192-use-highcharts-to-create-charts-in-react ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan yes that is what I am doing. It seems this issue happens when testing d3 components as well...

Comment: Unforutnately Im not experienced with the D3 library.